# Simple Calculator (GUI) Causing Exception

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a simple calculator with a graphical user interface; however, I'm having trouble adding two values from the text fields. Each time I try and calculate the values, I receive an exception. Could someone help me out with this? I'm fairly new to java, and I'm open to feedback and suggestions. The exception is down below.

Thank you,

Kyle

```
public class Calculator extends Application 
{
private Label firstValue;
private Label secondValue;
private Label sum;
private Button myButton;
private TextField textSum;
private TextField textFirst;
private TextField textSecond;

public String calculation()
{
    String getTextFirst = textFirst.getText();
    String getTextSecond = textSecond.getText();

    int total = Integer.parseInt(getTextFirst) + 
    Integer.parseInt(getTextSecond);
    String realTotal = String.valueOf(total);
    return realTotal;
}

public void start(Stage myStage)
{

    myStage.setTitle("Simple Calculator");
    GridPane rootNode = new GridPane();
    rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    rootNode.setPadding(new Insets(30));
    Scene myScene = new Scene (rootNode, 400 , 300);
    firstValue = new Label ("First Value: ");
    secondValue = new Label ("Second Value: ");
    sum = new Label ("Sum is: ");

    textFirst = new TextField();
    textSecond = new TextField();
    textSum = new TextField();

    textSum.setEditable(false);
    myButton = new Button ("Calculate");

    rootNode.add(firstValue, 1, 0);
    rootNode.add(textFirst, 2, 0);
    rootNode.add(secondValue, 1, 1);
    rootNode.add(textSecond, 2, 1);
    rootNode.add(sum, 1, 2);
    rootNode.add(textSum, 2, 2);
    rootNode.add(myButton, 2, 3);

    myButton.setOnAction(new ButtonHandler());


    myStage.setScene(myScene);
    myStage.show();



}

class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Calculator finalTotal = new Calculator();

        myButton.setText("Calculating");

        textSum.setText(finalTotal.calculation());
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
}
```

[Simple Calculator Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7pA8.png)

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Calculator.calculation(Calculator.java:22)
at Calculator$ButtonHandler.handle(Calculator.java:75)
at Calculator$ButtonHandler.handle(Calculator.java:1)
```

Comment: Do you really need to create a new instance of `Calculator` in the action handler?

Comment: you should share what the exception is

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("Causing Exception") must include the desired behavior, a **specific** problem or error and the **shortest** code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

To start with, your `ButtonHandler` is creating a new instance of `Calculator` which has nothing to do with the instance of `Calculator` which is currently displayed on the screen

```
class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Calculator finalTotal = new Calculator();

        myButton.setText("Calculating");

        textSum.setText(finalTotal.calculation());
    }
}
```

This would mean that when `calculation` is called...

```
public String calculation()
{
    String getTextFirst = textFirst.getText();
    String getTextSecond = textSecond.getText();

    int total = Integer.parseInt(getTextFirst) + Integer.parseInt(getTextSecond);
    String realTotal = String.valueOf(total);
    return realTotal;
}
```

Since your UI components are created in the `start` method, which is never called when you create the second instance, both `textFirst` and `textSecond` are `null`

Start by modifying your handler to take a reference to the `Calculator`

```
class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{
    private Calculator calculator;

    public ButtonHandler(Calculator calculator) {
        this.calculator = calculator
    }

    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
        this.calculator.calculation();
    }
}
```

This when, actioned, you can simply all the `calculation` of the instance of `Calculator` which is actually on the screen

You will then need to update the creation of the handler...

```
myButton.setOnAction(new ButtonHandler(this));
```

And finally, I would update the `calculation` to update the UI, as the fields are `private`...

```
public void calculation()
{
    String getTextFirst = textFirst.getText();
    String getTextSecond = textSecond.getText();

    int total = Integer.parseInt(getTextFirst) + Integer.parseInt(getTextSecond);
    String realTotal = String.valueOf(total);

    textSum.setText(realTotal);
}
```

Comment: *"`textFirst.getText()` and `textSecond.getText()` will either return null or an empty String, which is likely the cause of your exception"* Nope, afaik `getText` never returns `null`, but a empty string which would result in a `NumberFormatException` not a NPE. For the new `Calculator` instance `textFirst` and `textSecond` are not initialized.

Comment: @fabian Yes, but when I answered, all I had was "an exception", so it was a little but of guess work - There updated